# Restart GIF Image from starting after some time of stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif

I have set GIF Image and its working fine but i have one query regarding it and that is how can i restart that GIF image after some time without refreshing page.

I have search alot but any solution is not working for me.

I have set code like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('document').ready(function(){
            function func() {
                //alert('Here');
                var d = new Date();
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = 'http://www.goldenswange.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/stoptyre.gif';
                jQuery("#gifimg").attr("src", img.src + '?s=' + d.getTime());
                timer = setTimeout(func, 30000)
            }
            var timer = setTimeout(func, 30000)
            /*setInterval(function(){
                //alert('hy');
                var d = new Date();
               // var img_path = 'http://www.goldenswange.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/stoptyre.gif?' + d.getTime();
               var img = new Image();
               img.src = 'http://www.goldenswange.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/stoptyre.gif';
               jQuery("#gifimg").attr("src", img.src + '?s=' + d.getTime());
            },32000);*/
        });
</script>
```

But its not woking well.

Any help will be appreciate and waiting for right answer.

You can see this at here : [Link](http://www.goldenswange.com/work/used-tyers/)

Comment: If you always want to “restart” it after 30 seconds, then probably the easiest solution would be to implement that within the GIF in the first place, by making it repeat its animation. / “Re-starting” a GIF animation cross-browser is not the most trivial thing to do; there are good reasons why most big sites dealing with animated GIFs convert them to videos nowadays – those are a lot easier to control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the `src` then put the original again. Here is an example.
Run the snippet and let me know if this works for you.

I have used button to refresh the image, you can use as per your scenario.

```js
function test1(){
jQuery('#myimg').attr('src','placeholder.png');
jQuery('#myimg').attr('src','http://www.goldenswange.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/stoptyre.gif');
}
```

```css
#myimg{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:0px none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="test1();">
refresh image
</button>
<img id="myimg" src="http://www.goldenswange.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/stoptyre.gif" alt="dgfdgdf gfd gdfg fdsg dfs gdfsgdfsgdfg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead of `setTimeout`

```
function func() {
  var d = new Date();
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://www.goldenswange.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/stoptyre.gif';
  jQuery("#gifimg").attr("src", img.src + '?s=' + d.getTime());
}
var timer = setInterval(func, 30000);
```